# Run-time error '1004' - Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed when trying to hide columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to hide several non-continuous columns, but my macro kicks back with the 1004 error.

I tried some of the fixes for similar problems in other questions, but I get the same error.

```
Sub Hide_Columns()
Worksheets("Fast Track").Range("A,F:H,N,Q:X,AB:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried exactly? Is the worksheet the currently active worksheet? have you tried using a single range, expanding to two columns, seeing if this causes the error? There seems to be quite a few fixed, and without concrete error specification or more information, it will be difficult to provide a good answer to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A` and `N` aren't valid references:

```
Sub Hide_Columns()
    Worksheets("Fast Track").Range("A:A,F:H,N:N,Q:X,AB:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, glad to help.